# Create random string that can be used as query in a link

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor, cryptography

I am trying to create a random string that will act as a token for resetting the password. Once generated, I will store the 'key' in my database and send the user a link via email to reset his password (e.g. page.com/?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)

I have been trying to use the following code:

```
RandomNumberGenerator rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
byte[] randomBytes = new byte[30];
rng.GetBytes(randomBytes);
string randKey = Convert.ToBase64String(randomBytes);
```

Which seems to create the random string quiet well, but the problem is that it sometimes uses the reserved characters (/, +, etc.) which break my key when trying to read it of the query string.

Is there any way to generate the key without above characters? I know I can use randKey.Replace() but I would have to do it for all the different characters and I am not so sure that would be the best approach.

Comment: ASP.NET Core Identity has exactly the method that you want in UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Base64UrlEncoder`. It basically encodes to base64 in an url friendly format. You can find more info about it [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Html encode and decode method
Refer this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmlencode

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I've tried using HtmlEncode(randKey) but it still produces the same string. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: If it possible send the random string which causes the error.

Comment: To encode or decode values outside of a web application, use the WebUtility class.   Remarks from the documentation site

Comment: So I've generated a randKey = /ezsn7DcvaPIoLD++fnZfD/mrxlL5g0VpY8pBjS9 I tried to use both HttpUtility and WebUtility HtmlEncode() and store it in a string called encoded. However, when I display the randkey and encoded variables they are the same.

Comment: You try to pass it as a query string . Instead of dispalying. Again you face the same issue I'll send a demo code based on your randkey